# Screwy MySQL Code Logic

Tags: php, mysql

1. The `default_albums` table is used for storing album data.
2. The `default_hottest_categories` table is used to store the category
   data
3. The `default_album_hc_connect` table is used to connect the `default_hottest_categories` table with the `default_albums`
   table.

I need to be able to display all albums that are apart of the category which `is_hottest`. the `is_hottest` column is located in the `default_hottest_categories` table. The below code is what I have so far:

```
$q1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM default_albums a, default_hottest_categories d INNER JOIN default_album_hc_connect dc
                        ON d.id = dc.hottest_categories_id INNER JOIN default_albums ON dc.albums_id = default_albums.album_id
                        WHERE d.is_hottest = 'Yes'");
```

I really do not know if this is correct or not. So if you can help me, I'd much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.  You had an extra instance of the default_albums table in your `FROM` clause.  I removed that.  Also you generally want to join all your tables together.  The comma you had in there is used for CROSS JOINS, but is not used that often and is not needed in this case.  Also I would recommend only taking the fields you need in your `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT * 

FROM   default_albums a

       INNER JOIN default_album_hc_connect dc
       ON a.albums_id = dc.album_id

       INNER JOIN default_hottest_categories d 
       ON dc.hottest_categories_id = d.id

WHERE  d.is_hottest = 'Yes'"
```